# measure RDP time to login

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, command-line-interface, remote-desktop

I have a requirement to, for a short while, measure the login time to remote desktop services. I have found a fork of "rdesktop", called "rdesktop-nogui", which is without X bindings and is possible to run where X is not available. Its login succeed, but then nothing happens. I tried to execute "cmd.exe exit" but nothing will make it exit.

Is there a solid way of doing what I want?

```
./rdesktop-nogui -s "cmd.exe exit" <host>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the server, install and run the [Windows Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162945.aspx). It will show you pretty visualizations with time bars, and probably help narrow down what's failing.